# How to make close button of MAIN WINDOW unable in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want to make an `X` button (close button) of the `MAIN WINDOW` unable when the modal window is opened.

I tried to find the answer what I was looking for, but there weren't the answer that I wanted.

I really emphasise that I want to make close button of `MAIN WINDOW` unable, NOT modal window (tkinter window).

I really looking for the answer.
Thanks.

Here's my code

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

class Gameover(object):
    def start(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title('Gameover')

        self.lbl = Label(self.root, text = 'Enter your name')
        self.lbl.grid(row = 0)

        self.usertext = StringVar()
        self.myentry = Entry(self.root, textvariable = self.usertext)
        self.myentry.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        self.lbl = Label(self.root, text = 'Your name's length must be shorter than 9 letters')
        self.lbl.grid(row = 2)

        self.mybutton = Button(self.root, text = 'OK', command = self.check_length, width = 10, height = 2)
        self.mybutton.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

        self.counter = 0

        self.root.mainloop()

    def check_length(self):
        if len(self.usertext.get()) < 10:
            self.printMessage()
        else:
            self.errorbox()

    def errorbox(self):
        messagebox.showinfo("Erorr", 'Your name's length must be shorter than 9 letters')

    def printMessage(self):
        global the_score, FILE_DATA

        data = [self.usertext.get(), str(the_score)]

        FILE_DATA.insert(len(FILE_DATA) - 1, data)
        FILE_DATA[len(FILE_DATA) - 2][1] = int(FILE_DATA[len(FILE_DATA) - 2][1])

        for i in range(0, len(FILE_DATA) - 1):
            for j in range(0, len(FILE_DATA) - 2 - i):
                if FILE_DATA[j][1] < FILE_DATA[j + 1][1]:
                    poped_data = FILE_DATA[j]
                    del FILE_DATA[j]
                    FILE_DATA.insert(j + 1, poped_data)

        file = open('score.txt', 'w', encoding = 'utf-8')
        for i in range(len(FILE_DATA) - 1):
            file.write('{} {}\n'.format(FILE_DATA[i][0], FILE_DATA[i][1]))
        file.close()
        sys.exit()
```

There's more code than this, but I think I don't need to write every code on here.

I want to make close button of MAIN WINDOW when this modal window (tkinter window) is opened.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to help people answering your question, you should provide us with some background information. What have you tried so far? You are more likely to trigger a response if you show that you have put some effort into the problem. Also, comments such as `OMG PLEASE HELP ME` does not help your case.

Comment: I apologize. I was mad because I came to grapples with this matter for 3 days. I searched for information, but maybe I tried wrong way, I couldn't find the answer. I will edit my question.

Comment: Your code has unbalanced quotes in it.

Comment: I have no idea what the _`MAIN WINDOW`_ supposed to be, hence question has no meaning to me.

Answer (score 0):

The window frame close button is handled in your Tkinter program by defining a [`wm_protocol`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#wm.Wm.protocol-method) handler for "WM_DELETE_WINDOW". The default handler exits your program but if you define a handler that doesn't exit you can ignore the window manager requests to exit.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk

def on_exit(label):
    label.configure(text="Not exiting")

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    label = tk.Label(text="")
    label.place(x=0,y=0)
    button = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
    button.place(x=120,y=80)
    root.wm_protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: on_exit(label))
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks. But what I wanted is to control the close button of MAIN WINDOW, not modal window. Is there any answer about this problem?

Comment: I want to make close button of main window unable or I want to ignore the close command

Comment: That  what this example does. The close button on the application window frame is provided by the window manager. To communicate the close request the window manager posts an event to your tkinter application that is represented in tkinter code using the wm_protocol WM_DELETE_WINDOW. If you really mean something else you need to ask your question better with some screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove the title bar as it is handled by the operating system, however this should ignore the close event whenever it is called

```
def __CancelCommand(event=None): pass    
    self.top.protocol( 'WM_DELETE_WINDOW', __CancelCommand )
```